# XMPP Ejabberd chat server

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I want to customize my ejabberd chat server for following functionality.

1. Group Chat
2. Broad Casting Messages
3. user logged in from 2 clients (as in web.whatsapp.com)

What config changes do I require for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ejabberd supports all the functionality you have mentioned.

1) Group Chat - The server should support [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) for Multi User Chat. Ejabberd supports that with the module [mod_muc](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) module. You can read the [mod_muc](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) docs for configuration

2) Broad Casting Messages - The server should support [XEP-0033](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) for Extended Stanza Messaging. Ejabberd supports this with [mod_multicast](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/72) module.

3) For user logging in through 2 clients, please read this https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/72

Comment: If my answer is useful then please accept the answer. So that other users can able to find the answer in easy

Comment: @Yashwanth hey buddy i need to implement ejabberd with ios , could you check this question posted on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/q/41423506/3400991