# Ejabber Configuration on Amazon for Chat application

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ejabberd

- **Ubuntu**
- **Ejabber**
- **Amazon (AWS)**

Created `t2 instance in AWS (Amazon) for congiguring Ejabberd Server` .
Created custom http and passed 5280 (Ejabber port) in place of 80 and through Ubuntu i tried to install Ejabber and register Admin as user . User registered succesfully.

I used `Ejabberdctl` command to check `Ejabberd status` and it showing it running and in the message it showing a private IP which is linked with my AWS ip .

But when same thing like : `36.159.103.47/admin/5280`  hit on URL then it shows nothing , no data retrieved .

I want to open `Ejabber Web admin page` , to check the

- Access Rule
- Users
- etc

Can someone help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: How did you install ejabberd in Amazon AWS server. Did you install using the binary installer or you installed using the source code?

Comment: created an instance and through ubuntu try to install it through command on amazon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally configured Ejabberd on Amazon . Need to pass custom http rule and always need to whitelist iP address. It was appending any alphanumeric domain : `youripaddress:5280/admin`  (

```
Username : username@domain password: password)
```

Solved it .